# Vimeo Gem API Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a vimeo account that I would like to link the videos from my account to posts in my rails app.

I have the [Vimeo Gem](https://github.com/matthooks/vimeo) and I'm having difficulty understanding how I implement the API within my post.

For each post created I want to link a video file to the post based on a column from my database which I input the video id.

Does anyone know of any tutorials or example regarding this gem?

Schema

```
create_table "vimeo", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "vimeo_clip_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    :null => false
  end
```

Controller

Show

```
@vimeo = Vimeo.find(params[:id])
@video = Vimeo.where(:vimeo_clip_id)
@vimeo = Vimeo::Simple::Video.info(@video)
```

View

```
<p><%= @vimeo.title %></p>
```

Outputs 'video_id is not a valid method.'.

Not sure how to implement the API so it recognises my Vimeo user id and then displays the video as per my video_clip_id I input.

Comment: The GitHub page you linked to has examples on it.

Comment: Thanks jcm, I'm lost on how to implement these examples in my controller.

Comment: I haven't used this gem (or the Vimeo API) before either.  What does `Vimeo::Simple::Video.info("video_id")` give you?

Comment: I have updated my post above, but I get a 'video_id is not a valid method.' error.

Comment: You have to replace `video_id` with the actual video id, the `vimeo_clip_id` value.

Comment: So for example in the console I tried `Vimeo::Simple::Video.info "78673338"` and got back a response with the title, description, links and lots of other metadata.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with your latest edit.  But first, how are you getting the `vimeo_clip_id`?  If all you want is to create a link in the `show` page, maybe you can add a column/attribute for the link.  Then upon creating a `Vimeo` object make a call to the API to set that attribute.

Comment: Well I was going to enter the id manually into the form or call from a collection (but i cant seem to get that working wither). For my show page I hope to display the video as a embedded view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `video_id` with the `vimeo_clip_id` value.  For example in the console

```
Vimeo::Simple::Video.info "78673338"
```

returns

```
<HTTParty::Response:0x7ff09a9076e8 large_chunk_of_data_here>
```

You can create the link you want with the data you receive.  In your controller:

```
def show
  @vimeo = Vimeo.find params[:id]
  @link_url = Vimeo::Simple::Video.info(@vimeo.vimeo_clip_id)[0]['url']
end
```

and in the view:

```
link_to @vimeo.title, @link_url
```

**Please note the following:**

- The controller code can be cleaned up.  You probably don't want to be doing the retrieving of the link URL in the controller every time the show page is rendered.  Instead you want to be storing that information with your Vimeo object.
- Inspect the response from the Vimeo API to find out what the `[0]['url']` part does.
- The view code just displays a text link.  You can explore other options such as a preview image later.

Comment: Did you use the same id or a different one?

Comment: Thanks jcm. The above outputted: [{"id"=>78673338, "title"=>"Never Not Part 2" ..etc}] but I need it to reference my account then hit the vimeo_clip_id. I can get all of my account info using: Vimeo::Simple::User.videos("username") in [{""}]. How do I go about referencing my vimeo_clip_id in the api code? Can't do vimeo = Vimeo.Vimeo::Simple::Video.info("video_id"). Sorry this is all new to me, rails and API.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "I need it to reference my account then hit the vimeo_clip_id" means.

Comment: Sorry I think I follow now. No need to hit my user account as the video Id's are unique. SO my next question is how do i reference the  vimeo_clip_id in the API? I have updated my show above to what i have now, but is outputting 'bad URI(is not URI?): /video/#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000102b6b928>.json'

Comment: Perfect. Worked a treat. Can't thank you enough for all your help jcm. Now i'll just have to play around and figure out how to embed the video.